# How to get BAK files from SQL 2008 R2 to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-backups

I know from SQL 2012 you can backup directly to Azure, but I have a SQL 2008 R2 instance where I'm needing to get the backups up to Azure for off-site backup reasons.

Anyone have some good options for what could be considered here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a PowerShell script, which will backup your database using [Backup-SqlDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/backup-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps) cmdlet, and then copy the BAK file to Azure Blob Storage using [Set-AzureStorageBlobContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/set-azurestorageblobcontent?view=azurermps-6.12.0) cmdlet. Of course, you can also use your existing backup solution, but it may be more difficult to plug the call to Set-AzureStorageBlobContent in it. If you use SQL Server Agent, you can add a step with PowerShell or call to external executable to upload the recently made backup.

```
# Upload file from local disk to Azure Blob Storage
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container "SQLServerBackups" -File "E:\Backups\MyDatabase-2018-01-01.bak" -Blob "MyDatabase-2018-01-01"
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey, that sounds like a really good solution. :)  Will test it out.